# Automatic network Installation

Tags: networking, automation, installation, windows-installer, aspen

Recently I have been attempting to install a software package automatically over a moderately sized computer network for a university lab. The package is aspenOne v8.4. I have tried creating response files, but every time I finish the install I am unable to locate the response file. I included the f1 flag option to specify file location and name, and I have also checked the %systemroot% directory as well, to no avail. I do not believe one is being created. I have also tried creating a response file for the msi package included on the disc with msiexec, but I was unsuccessful in that path as well. The install requires too much time to install manually across the network, so I was hoping there might be another option to automatically deploy the application package throughout the network. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So I have continued to search and just found this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/184304584/Unattended-Install-Help  I think this is what I needed. I will try this and post results.

Comment: So after using the above guide I was able to create a response file. I am still, however, unsure of how to deploy this entire software suite across the network.

Comment: Automatic deploy is a subject which is not trivial. I know about a number of companies who have a whole expert team working at it- permanently, not as a project. Selfprogrammed solutions can cost a company quickly some million dollars over the time. There are no professional tools available without costs. In the easiest try you have to invest a bunch of time to do some scripting. You could start by making a list of your network clients and write a script to loop over that list, copy the stuff locally (this is always advised because of stability), and then start the installation remote.

Comment: Thanks. We were able to make the response file and run the installation unattended locally, but when deploying the package across the network, for some reason the script failed. The package was setup to copy everything to a folder on the local machine and then to run a batch script which would run the installation. If the batch script was manually executed on the client, it would run correctly. But for some reason, when it is triggered from the script on the server, the installation does not complete successfully. We are attempting to run down the problem, as I believe this one is on our end.